# Kibana: adding a field that matches a word in the message

Tags: logstash, kibana

I'm new at ELK-stack and want to add a field in kibana(discover) interface that matches a specific part of the message text (one word or a sentence).

for example:
I want to have a field in the left side that matches the word 'installed' in the message text.

Which filter in logstash should I use and how does it look like?

[image: kibana/discover]

Answer (score 0):

How about [grok{}](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html), which applies a regular expression to your input message and can make new fields?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I used grok as following to match how many users created new accounts.

```
   grok {
match   =>  [ "message", "(?<user_created>(user_created))"]
break_on_match => false
}
```

Anyway I found out the problem is that Kibana is showing old logs and doesn't care what I do in the logstash config file! still can't find out why!